# Special rotation calculation

Tags: javascript, html, math, rotation, compass

I'm currently working on some kind of a special-compass.

The project is working quite fine and also not that important to mention in this question because I just got big problems by one part of the project:

---

My code is returning a calculated degree angle that could be *(values between -360 and 360)*:

```
-318°, -29°, 223°, -163°, ...
```

Because of my weird (but working) calculation I'm not getting angles from **0° to 360°** but for example I'm getting values between **42° to -317°** or **25° to -334°**.

> For rotating an image for the specific rotation this behavior doesn't causes issues because **-317°** is nearly the same as **42°** in relation to a circular rotation.

---

My issue: For my project it's NOW important to get the rotation in default angles like from `0% to 100%` (like 0°-360°). How can I get those angle-range instead?

```js
function rotate(val) {
  div.style.transform = "rotate("+val+"deg)"
  div.innerHTML = val + "°"
}
rotate(26)
```

```css
div {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 10%;
  margin-left:-30px;
  background: black;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue;
  font-size: 30px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 160%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p><b>(!) Try</b>: Input "25" and "-334"</p>

<input type="number" value="25" onchange="rotate(this.value)" placeholder="input degree">
<div id="div">[]</div>
```

> My QUESTION: How can I calculate the rotation of the images in percent (from 0%-100%)?

Edit: Just using

```
var percentageRotation = myweirdrotation/3.6
```

will not solve the problem at all. It will not output values between 0 and 100. There also this weird "jump" inside.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution on myself

Using this code will do the job:

```
var rot = (myweirdrotation%360) / 3.6
```